# Chaining confusion

Tags: jquery, chaining

Say I have this HTML:

```
<div id="div_box">
    <ul>
        <li class="li1"></li>
        <li class="li2"></li>
        <li class="li3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to remove the class "li1".

I tried this with jQuery:

```
$("#div_box").find(".li1").removeClass("li1");
```

It works, but what I don't understand is why does it work. In chaining, the method only applies to the selector given.  But `#div_box` does not have a class called "li1" so this shouldn't work.

Am I misunderstanding how chaining works?  Could someone clarify on why this works?

Comment: Did you bother reading the manual?  [_"`.find()` ~ Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element."_](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is clearly spelled out in the manual and therefore unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method return all the descendants of `#div_box` which is having the class `li1`...

not all jQuery methods return the same set of objects on which it was called upon... mostly the [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) methods returns a different set of objects

Answer (score 0):

it is well explained in the documentation... http://api.jquery.com/find/

> the `.find()` method **allows us to search through the descendants of
>   these elements in the DOM tree** and construct a new jQuery object from
>   the matching elements.
>
> The first signature for the .find()method accepts a selector
>   expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. The
>   elements will be filtered by testing whether they match this selector.

with the concern of traversing to the elements

> Unlike in the rest of the tree traversal methods, the selector
>   expression is required in a call to .find(). If we need to retrieve
>   all of the descendant elements, we can pass in the universal selector
>   '*' to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining will points to the `object` which is `evaluated` recently, In your case the recently evaluated `object` is the out come of `.find('.li1')`. If you want to add that `#div_box` into the selector then you have to use `.addBack()` in your current context.